# Issue with Channel Images on local setup

Tags: channel-images, devdemon

We've taken over a site and I've set up a copy on my local setup mostly successfully. The problem I'm having is getting the following PHP errors:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Channel_images_model::$LOCS
Filename: models/channel_images_model.php
Line Number: 568

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /my/path/to/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 408
```

This is on EE 2.7.2 and Channel Images 5.4.8.

I've looked at permissions - they're all correct. I'm able to get into EE just fine, as well as the Channel Images module. However, if I try to regenerate images, nothing happens.

Not sure what to try next. I've been waiting to hear from DevDemon support for over a week. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer and fix: upgrade to Channel Images 5.4.17.

Answer (score 3):

I was also having this issue and found another way to fix it without updating; open third_party/channel_images/models/channel_images_model.php and edit line 525:

Make this line

```
$this->LOCS &= $this->session->cache['channel_images']['locations'];
```

Look like this

```
$this->LOCS = $this->session->cache['channel_images']['locations'];
```

Done. Does anyone know if this will break functionality elsewhere? I haven't encountered it if it does.

Comment: good quickndirty fix gmask :) but Ill update later as bad idea to edit config files for legacy issues ;)

Comment: Really good fix in case your client forgot his account data and can't update.